# C++ how to call a class by using an element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am creating a Pokémon Battle Simulator, and I want to know if I can call a class by using an element of an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

string PokémonArray[] = { "Pikachu","Pidgey" };

class Pokémon {
public:
    string basic_attack;
    int basic_attack_dmg;

    string getBasicAttackName() { return basic_attack; }

Pokémon() { ; }
};

class Pikachu : public Pokémon {
public:
    Pikachu(){ basic_attack = "Whatever"; }
};

int main(){
int random_num;
string randEnemy;

srand(TIME(NULL));
random_num = rand() % 2; //Generates a random number between 0 and 1

randEnemy = PokémonArray[random_num]; //Sets randEnemy to be equal to the element 0 or 1 (generated above) of the array

(randEnemy) enemy; //Try to create the object 'enemy' calling a class using an element of the array

}
```

How can I call the class by using an element of an array that has the same name?

Comment: Why do you make an array of strings instead of an array of pokemons?

Comment: Are you trying to spawn a random enemy based on the random number? Meaning there are only two types of enemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly - yes you can, but you will need lots of if/else statements and you will have to use the polymorphic base.

```
Pokemon* pokemon = nullptr;
if(randEnemy == "Pikachu")
    pokemon = new Pikachu;
else if (randEnemy == "Raichu")
    pokemon = new Raichu;
else if...
```

This pattern is called "Factory method" or "virtual constructor".

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) store the `Pokemon` in the array directly, but it will not be so simple as the other answer specifies, as apparently the `Pokemon` instances are polymorphic. So what you need to store is a pointer to the `Pokemon` instance.

At the best a smart pointer (for automatic destruction). Depending on the use, it can be either:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pokemon> > PokemonArray;
```

or

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Pokemon> > PokemonArray;
```

(depending whether or not the pointer instance can be owned by multiple owners)

Or a simple array, but I generally prefer the `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the Pokemon in your array.

```
Pokemon PokémonArray[152];
```

And then just call their function directly once you need them.

```
randEnemy = PokémonArray[random_num];
randEnemy.basicAttack();
```